# Google Home API to control home devices

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

Is it possible to trigger an action on a device without going through the Assistant ?

The use-case: I have a bunch of Lutron Caseta dimmers (they are great!) hooked up to Google Home and I'd like to have a motion detector open the lights. I'd rather build on Google Home than on the Lutron platform.

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no Google Home API. When connecting your smart devices, you connect them through the Google Assistant. As such, controlling a device would have to go through the Assistant.

There are many ways to make the experience better, such as creating [routines](https://support.google.com/googlehome/answer/7029585?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en) to run many actions at once.

With regards to your use-case, the Google Assistant doesn't support triggers for things like motion detection. What you could do is use the [Google Assistant SDK](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/overview) to programmatically control the Assistant.

You could set up the motion sensor to execute a text query of "turn on the lights". It will be processed by the Assistant and execute as expected. The [Node.js](https://github.com/googlesamples/assistant-sdk-nodejs) code sample shows how you can send these commands.