# Is there an Android/iOS API for a 3rd party app to control Google Home linked devices?

Tags: google-smart-home

I'm looking to create a mobile app that controls lights that are connected to a Google Home, is this possible?  I'm basically looking for a Google Home equivalent to Apple's HomeKit framework.

This is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54120965/google-home-api-to-control-home-devices), but also three years old, so I'm wondering if anything has changed, or changing soon with Matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The platform does not give programmatic access to developers to the devices in their home. In this regard nothing has changed up to this point. I cannot speculate what may happen in the future.