# Using google API using OAuth2 in Postman or Java/Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, oauth-2.0, postman, google-oauth

I am here to ask you a for a help with OAuth2 for Google API.

Short story: I am trying to access Google Home through API to use Air Condition.

I saw many tutorials on this, but since google is changing it's api very often I don't know how to continue.

I already have a client ID which I made through Google Console. Now I need to create OAuth2 token to communicate with the API either through Postman or directly from Android Kotlin app.

Google console gave me following parameters:

**client_id,
project_id,
auth_uri,
token_uri,
auth_provider_x509_cert_url**

According to this site: [GoogleSite](https://developers.home.google.com/cloud-to-cloud/project/authorization) I can see that there should be other types of parameters (Or I am wrong maybe?)

Can someone help me with getting OAuth2 Token either from Postman or Java/Kotlin ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you aware you are using a service account.   This is not going to let you authoze to a uaers account.   If you are working with android I suspect you should have created android credentials

Comment: do you have a tutorial or something please? Like I said.. maybe I did something wrong and I am not aware of this.

Comment: Depends upon what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have my Air Condition in my Google Home. I am trying to get some information from it  and possibly control it through API

Comment: Unless this device has an open api itself that you can connect to then probably not.  Any device that is hooked up to your wifi (wtf you if you have a wifi enabled air conditioner) its probably going to be locked down by the company that built it.  My thermostats on my radiator are connected to the companies i bought them form's cloud system but its no a system I am allowed to connect to.

Comment: well.. I have HiSense AC.. They dont have public API, but they insist that it is possible to connect the account to Google Home or Amazon Alexa.. I was able to control it through these two, so I think that it is somehow possible to use API to control it... Correct me please if I am wrong in some way please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand Cloud to Cloud API is for device manufacturers. Google focusing on getting every provider compatible with Google Home, so users can use it. I smell [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) here. There's extensive docs on [OAuth](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2), but I think you rather need a way to talk to Google Home's Assistant backend, just like Google Home / Nest / your phone does.

I think you need this approach: talk to Assistant with text prompts to control your things.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54135312/253468

For that I would follow this tutorial:

https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/service/python

here's some code that looks promising:

https://github.com/googlesamples/assistant-sdk-nodejs

You can choose another language you're more comfortable with:

https://github.com/orgs/googlesamples/repositories?q=assistant-sdk

Comment: I quickly looked at your answer.. And I will try to do it in my Kotlin app... thanks a lot :)